# How to download file in Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, file, blob

I am making an api call to export excel file and api is returning the response as encoded zip file like,

```
PK-[Content_Types].xmlµSËnÂ0ü•È×*6ôPUCÇ©ô\{“Xø%¯¡ð÷]8”R‰
qòcfgfWöd¶q¶ZCB|ÃÆ|Ä*ð*hã»†},^ê{Va–^K<4lÈfÓÉb+ªõØ°>çø ªœD"xBÚœÌtLˆR-eâv4º*ø>×¹h°éä  Z¹²¹zÜÝé†É­Q2S,±öúH´Þòvà`o"ÞUÏRÙµC(2q†Ãqa9SÝ
& ........... goes on .......
```

So the above response needs to be converted into downloadable excel file.

For which I have used the following code,

```
const outputFilename = `${Date.now()}.xls`;
const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', outputFilename);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

It generate an excel file but when I open the file, it says that the file format is unsupported.

Could you please help me with steps to convert the response data into an real downloadable excel file without issues?

*I am using **reactjs** app for the implementation*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the [file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) begins with `PK`, we know it's a [`.zip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) archive (which any newer Excel files are).  So I don't think it's *encrypted* but likely just an *encoded* zip (binary) file

Comment: @ashleedawg, Updated the question! Thanks for your response. How could I make it as downloadbale?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example :

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

export const ExportCSV = ({csvData, fileName}) => {

    const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    const fileExtension = '.xlsx';

    const exportToCSV = (csvData, fileName) => {
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(csvData);
        const wb = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
        const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
        const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], {type: fileType});
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
    }

    return (
        <Button variant="warning" onClick={(e) => exportToCSV(csvData,fileName)}>Export</Button>
    )
}
```

Using these deps :

// install xsls and file-saver

```
npm install xlsx file-saver --save
```

Comment: I hope you are referring this link https://blog.bitsrc.io/exporting-data-to-excel-with-react-6943d7775a92 as answer but I have already gone through it and it dosn't work also I cannot install any third party library inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file extension xlxs format changed .xls into .xlxs

const outputFilename = `${Date.now()}.xlxs`;

and try